# Doctrine Why this query return 0 rows?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, select, doctrine

I have the following DQL query:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('id')
    ->from('Comment')
    ->where("active='?' AND object_id='?' AND group_name = '?'"
            , array(1, 1, 'unit'));
```

Which produce the sql:

```
SELECT c.id AS c__id, c.group_name AS c__group_name, c.name AS c__name,
       c.email AS c__email
  FROM comment c
 WHERE (c.active = '?' AND c.object_id = '?' AND c.group_name = '?')

bindings: 1, 1, unit
```

In database table:

```
id user_id object_id group_name name  active
1   0      1         unit       test  1
```

When I execute de query it returns 0 rows. Why?

If I go in `phpmyadmin` and I run

```
SELECT * FROM comment WHERE active=1 AND object_id=1 AND group_name='unit'
```

the result contains the record I look for.

In phpmyadmin the query generated by Doctrine identify the table name as 'c'. This is very strange, since I used in my application other DQL querys like this one and works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove quotes around parameter placeholders:

```
where("active=? AND object_id=? AND group_name = ?"
```

or use `named parameters`:

```
where("active= :ative AND object_id= :object_id AND group_name = :group_name"
      , array(':ative'=>1, ':objet_id'=>1, 'group_name'=>'unit')"
```

Comment: If I change it, I get an error, so I used '?': "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens